# Hover over thumbnails with absoloute position in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, thumbnails, css-position

I have created a grid of thumbnail pictures, that when hovered over, the picture dissapears a block colour is shown with the title of the image on. but In internet explorer instead of the pictures and text appearing within their set thumbnail space they all cramp up in the left corner.

The image and title are stored within the box/ category-widescreen div, this is a dynamic code for wordpress.

Any ideas?

```
#page-wrap {width: 1060px; padding-bottom: 40px;}
.box { margin: 20px; float: left; }

.category-widescreen { width: 400px; height: 229px; background: #FF0000; }
.category-widescreen a{text-decoration: none;}
.category-widescreen h1{font-size: 30px; color: #FFF; line-height: 34px;}
.category-widescreen h2{font-size: 26px; color: #FFF;  line-height: 30px;}

.title{position:absolute; top:14px; left:14px; z-index: 0; padding-right: 14px;}

.category-widescreen img { max-width: 400px; max-height: 229px; float: right; padding: 0 0 2px 10px; z-index:1; position:relative;}
```

Thankyou for any help!

Comment: Mind at least giving the basic html structure? ..and what would be best, actual example page ( http://www.jsfiddle.net )

Comment: http://www.amythornley.co.uk/blog/ (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too vague! As the other guy suggests, give the basic html structure. However, some observations:
Aren't the font sizes used a bit too big (30px and 26px)?;
title{position:absolute; ...} .... make sure that the parent is styled with position:relative otherwise it will become a mess;
how about floating? Are you making sure things are floated in the right direction?

Hope have helped or at least opened your eyes wide-open! ha ha ha ...

Comment: Thankyou position: relative worked on my box elelement.. some of the pictures are still off margin wise, but I will look into that now!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `position:relative` to your posts so that the absolutely positioned elements know where to follow.

Try this:

```
.post {
position:relative;
}
```